# Maven maven-resources-plugin copy target jar

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am trying to use the resources plug-in with the aim of copying the jar in the target directory to another directory (e.g. /target/runtime) once it has been built.

I can see resources are copied at the start of process, before the jar is built, so reading up on it seems I need to run this at validate phase, i.e. after the jar has been built. However this is not working. Other files are copied, but not the jar.

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/runtime</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/target/runtime</targetPath>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.jar</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: To be clear, you want the generated JAR both in `target` and `target/runtime`, or only in `target/runtime`?

Comment: In both target and target/runtime

Comment: Why do you need things like this? And very important why have you configured to do filtering for JAR files which is simply wrong!

Comment: Yes, this is a very weird thing to want to do... can you explain what problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
`<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.1</version>
              <type>jar</type>
              <overWrite>false</overWrite>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/alternateLocation</outputDirectory>
              <destFileName>optional-new-name.jar</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wars</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>`
```

Please refer to [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html) I have used this multiple times , seems to do the job.

Comment: I don't think the problem is to copy dependency jar to a certain location. The problem is to copy built jar to target/runtime.

Comment: this will not copy dependency jar the artifact here refers to the new built jar only and not the dependency jar,Please check the Apache maven link mentioned in the answer

Comment: Thanks. I got confused with Junit dependency mentioned here. The page you have referred to have different section where it specify how to copy built artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

The phase in your plugin definition for resource copying is defined as validate. The Jar is not built when this plugin runs. More information about lifecycle is defined [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

If you change the plugin phase as verify then it copies the file successfully as shown below,

[image: Sample Project]